# "16-bit DES encryption algorithm"

Tags: block-cipher, des, key-size

I need to use encryption software from [PSpice](https://www.pspice.com/) for my SPICE model. In a [user guide](https://www.ecadtools.com.au/documents/PSpice%2017.2%20User%20Guide%20(pspug).pdf) on page 71 they claim to use a "16-bit DES encryption algorithm". According to the wiki DES is using a 64-bit key. How is it possible to use 16-bit key instead of 64(56)-bit key? Or "16-bit" describes something else?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. [Cross-posting is not considered as ethical on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/403350). Please delete the copy that in on the [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63186925/1820553)

Comment: Looks like a typo in the documentation. My guess is they meant 56-bit.

Comment: @tum_ I thought that too, however, couldn't find an errata. The document last updated in July 2019 and it doesn't contain an errata or updates. The OP should contact to PSpice.

Comment: There is a 16-bit [simplified DES](https://www.cs.uri.edu/cryptography/dessimplified.htm) but it is meant for study, not for use. This PSpice 16-bit DES can be (1) a typo, (2) incompetence, (3) deliberately weak crypto. I notice it was introduced in release 16.5, and AES introduced in 16.6, perhaps because it quickly became evident 16-bit DES was a bad idea.